# How to move Google Logo Above the Transparent Action Bar Like Google Maps App ? Android

Tags: android, android-mapview

How to move Google Logo Above the Transparent Action Bar Like Google Maps App?

I have a MapsActivity which extends `SherlockMapActivity`:

```
class MapsActivity extends SherlockMapActivity
```

[image: img]

Please see the image above, I have to do same look in my `MapsActivity`, any ideas?

Comment: Please bear in mind that this may be a violation of the terms of service ("You agree that you will not remove, obscure, or alter any proprietary rights notices (including copyright and trademark notices, Terms of Use links, or Brand Features) that may be affixed to or provided through the Service."). I strongly encourage you to discuss this issue with qualified legal counsel before proceeding.

Comment: Can you post an image of what exactly you are looking for. The image in the question seems to be broken..

Answer (score 2):

Moving the Google logo from standard maps API violates the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms).

9.4(a):

> Content provided to you through the Service may contain the trade
>   names, trademarks, service marks, logos, domain names, and other
>   distinctive brand features of Google, its partners, or other third
>   party rights holders of content indexed by Google. **When Google
>   provides this attribution, *you must display it as provided* through the
>   Service or as described in the Maps APIs Documentation and may not
>   delete or in any manner alter these trade names, trademarks, service
>   marks, logos, domain names, and other distinctive brand features.**

9.4(b):

> You agree to include and display the "*powered by Google*" attribution
>   (and/or any other attribution(s) required by Google as described in
>   the Maps APIs Documentation) conspicuously on the page, in close
>   proximity and adjacent to the Service search box and Google search
>   results. If you use the standard Google search control, or the
>   standard Google search control form, this attribution will be included
>   automatically, and ***you agree not to modify*** or obscure this
>   automatically-generated attribution.

So based on section 9.4(a) & 9.4(b) of the terms, it seems it might not be a good idea.

Comment: I resolved it by using padding https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#map_padding